# CouchDB Modelling - Time filtered and group data

Tags: nosql, couchdb, theory, data-modeling

I'm trying to build up my understanding of the CouchDB and how to model data for some real world scenarios. I've done as many 'get me blog posts by date' as I can for now ;)

Given documents like so:

```
{
    "_id": "couch1",
    "_rev": "2-338d0a592ad1e5570000002b00000000",
    "eventType": "event1",
    "date": 1328805860000
}

{
    "_id": "couch2",
    "_rev": "1-1e0315c2e1ca7f5f0000002b00000000",
    "eventType": "event1",
    "date": 1328133600000
}

{
    "_id": "couch3",
    "_rev": "1-154cd416b78cb2ef0000002b00000000",
    "eventType": "event2",
    "date": 1325434920000
}
```

*Where the date is an epoch would it be possible to ask Couch to make a view where you asked for all "events" that happened betweem two timestamps and then group that data by the "eventType"?*

So using the above and assuming the timestamps passed in encompass those documents - we'd want to see output:

```
"event1": 2
"event2": 1
```

*Further info I have obtained*

I'm aware that Couch will sort by key so if I wanted a 'top 10' then that would be a second phase but I can handle that.

So the core problem here is that you are filtering by one column but then grouping by another?

If we use the following map function:

```
function (doc) {
  emit([doc.date, doc.eventType], doc.eventType);
}
```

with a `count` reduce function we see that because the timestamps are essentially unique Couch cannot group and key has the value 1.

So you can change the map function to the following:

```
function (doc) {
  emit([doc.eventType, doc.date], doc.eventType);
}
```

And then change the `group level` to 1 which will group correctly by event but your data cannot then be sliced by time because your primary ordering is by the event name, meaning that time ordering is now broken?

Do people have any war stories on this? Does this need to be done with re-reduce?

Many thanks in advance to anyone taking time to read this

Eggsy

Comment: The answers are great; however notice that sanning/selecting by key **A** and then grouping by key **B** is fundamentally a two-dimensional query; and CouchDB views are *always* one-dimension.

Comment: So we're saying essentially it can't be done in the most efficient manner and drive it on to the DB. We can always do the grouping on the client but we'd rather not. It seems that this kind of problem would be a typical form of analytics problem and I wonder if any other NoSQL solutions that are built for large scale data could perform such a task

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a view/list Combo:

View:

```
"eventByDate": 
{
  "map": "function(doc) { emit(doc.date, doc.eventType);}"
}
```

List:

```
"test": "function(head,req) {
  var eventO=new Object();
  while(row=getRow()) {
  if(eventO[row.value]==undefined) {
    eventO[row.value]=1;
  }else{
    eventO[row.value]++;
  }
 }
 send("[");
 for (var curEvent in eventO) {
  send ("{\"event\":\""+curEvent +"\",\"count\":"+eventO[curEvent]+"}");
 }
 send("]");
}"
```

Result:

```
[
{"event":"event2","count":1} 
{"event":"event1","count":2} 
]
```

But you have to order by count manually (i did not implement it) here or in your backend

Comment: Hi, Oliver. Nice to see you on Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a fixed number of event types? Is it a small, relatively static list?

If not, skip the rest of my answer.

If so, read on for a quick and dirty option.

You could change your map.js function to have multiple emit() functions based on the event type value.

```
if(eventType == event1 ) {emit(doc.date, {'eventType1': 1}
```

Repeating for each event type. Or, if you can change your documents to have the eventType1, eventType2, etc. as fields with 1 as the value, you can skip all the fancy if...then nonsense and just:

```
emit(doc.date, doc).
```

Then have your reduce.js function loop through the rows and add them to an object that would eventually look something like:

{eventType1: 25, eventType2: 2, ...}

```
for ( i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
    if ( values[i].eventType1 > 0) { eventType1 += 1 }
    if ( values[i].eventType2 > 0) { eventType2 += 1 }
    ...
}
```

Query that view without group or group=false and you should get a single record with a null key with your event types and their counts.

I have this working on a similar type of request. But I my "eventType" list never changes.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Thank you for the idea though. The event that happens can never be known in advance and could grow to a large size.

Comment: Your best bet then is to go with the List function. Or look for chainable map/reduce if your eventType list gets really large.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as @user791770 shows, but not have to hard-code the list of event types by changing the code slightly.

Map:

```
function(doc) {
  var data = {};
  data[doc.type] = 1;
  emit(doc.time, data);
}
```

Reduce:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce) {
  var data = {};
  for ( i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var field in values[i]) {
      if (typeof data[field] == 'undefined') data[field] = 0;
      data[field] += values[i][field];
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```